# Using external scripts in Meteor executed from "script src"

Tags: meteor

I want to use a script on my web site and I know that I must put all scripts separated from the template in a .js file. But I don't know how to do it this time when the script is executed directly in the script src:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://svenskfotboll.se/widget.aspx?scr=table&amp;ftid=39662&amp;b1=%23006bb7&amp;f1=%23ffffff&amp;b2=%23bfd4f3&amp;f2=%23000000&amp;b3=%23ffffff&amp;f3=%23000000&amp;b4=%23ececec&amp;bo=%23ffffff&amp;s=1"></script>
```

What is the best practice to get it to work in Meteor?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go to that url, get that script, and save it in a file in your project. However, there wasn't anything actually at that url when I just checked it out. That would definitely be a problem too :)

EDIT: You can also stick in the `head` tag.

EDIT 2: if you want it to display in a template, like if it's a widget such as yours, you can insert it manually every time the template re-renders. It's pretty simple, actually. First we've got the template code:

```
Template.myWidget.rendered = function () {
    $('#my-widget').html('<script src="src-here.js"></script');
}
```

And then the actual template:

```
<template name="myWidget">
    <div id="my-widget">Loading...</div>
</template>
```

Finally, wherever you want the widget to appear in your html, just insert `{{>myWidget}}`

Comment: I've tried to save the script and load it locally but when I do that the information sent in the script becomes static and doesn't update anymore.

Comment: Then, have you tried putting it in the template? I'd try sticking it in the `head` tag.

Comment: I have also tried to put it directly in the Template but that does not work, and when I use it in the <head> it works but it is a widget that I don't want on the top of the page

Comment: Ok. In that case, there's a slightly hacky solution which I'm adding to the answer

Comment: Anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery.getScript(): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

In your case:

```
$.getScript( "http://svenskfotboll.se/widget.aspx?scr=table&amp;ftid=39662&amp;b1=%23006bb7&amp;f1=%23ffffff&amp;b2=%23bfd4f3&amp;f2=%23000000&amp;b3=%23ffffff&amp;f3=%23000000&amp;b4=%23ececec&amp;bo=%23ffffff&amp;s=1" );
```

You can also specify callback for success or failure (please see documentation linked above).