# Javascript in my Meteor app still not working

Tags: javascript

I originally posted this [How can I load js into my templates with Meteor/handlebars.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712805/how-can-i-load-js-into-my-templates-with-meteor-handlebars-js)

and thought I had a solution to my issue. I was wrong. I have some external js I want to load as well as an internal script. I tried placing the scripts in a template alone for example:

```
<template name="myscripts">
  <script src="myexternalscript"></script>
  <script src="anotherexternalscript></script>
  <script src="anotherexternalscript"></script>
  <script>
  //internal script code here
  </script>
</template>
```

then on the template with the html I want those scripts to affect, which contains html named "myothertemplate", I added

```
{{myscripts}}
```

to the bottom of those elements where I wanted it to load. Then that template which contains the html elements and the {{myscripts}} which I want to load the JavaScript, is loaded on my main page in the body {{>myothertemplate}}. I run my project, localhost:3000 and get no errors. I see the scripts I wanted there on the page where I wanted them as well but they don't work. They have no affect on the page. I tried taking the internal JavaScript and saving it as a JavaScript file as well as the external JavaScript files however this is not working either. This is an example of what I want:

```
<!--HTML here-->
<!--some elements here
after the last div on this template page, I wanted to add my scripts.-->
<div>
</div>
<script src="some external script"></script>
<script src="some external script"></script>
<!--Now my internal script-->
<script>
(function() {

    // Base template
    var base_tpl =
        "<!doctype html>\n" +
        "<html>\n\t" +
        "<head>\n\t\t" +
        "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\t\t" +
        "<title>Test</title>\n\n\t\t\n\t" +
        "</head>\n\t" +
        "<body>\n\t\n\t" +
        "</body>\n" +
        "</html>";

    var prepareSource = function() {
        var html = html_editor.getValue(),
            css = css_editor.getValue(),
            js = js_editor.getValue(),
            src = '';

        src = base_tpl.replace('</body>', html + '</body>');

        css = '<style>' + css + '</style>';
        src = src.replace('</head>', css + '</head>');

        js = '<script>' + js + '<\/script>';
        src = src.replace('</body>', js + '</body>');

        return src;
    };

    var render = function() {
        var source = prepareSource();

        var iframe = document.querySelector('#output iframe'),
            iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;

        iframe_doc.open();
        iframe_doc.write(source);
        iframe_doc.close();
    };

    var cm_opt = {
        mode: 'text/html',
        gutter: true,
        lineNumbers: true,
    };

    var html_box = document.querySelector('#html textarea');
    var html_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(html_box, cm_opt);

    html_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
        render();
    });


    cm_opt.mode = 'css';
    var css_box = document.querySelector('#css textarea');
    var css_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(css_box, cm_opt);

    css_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
        render();
    });

    cm_opt.mode = 'javascript';
    var js_box = document.querySelector('#js textarea');
    var js_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(js_box, cm_opt);

    js_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
        render();
    });


    var cms = document.querySelectorAll('.CodeMirror');
    for (var i = 0; i < cms.length; i++) {

        cms[i].style.position = 'absolute';
        cms[i].style.top = '30px';
        cms[i].style.bottom = '0';
        cms[i].style.left = '0';
        cms[i].style.right = '0';
        cms[i].style.height = '100%';
    }
    /*cms = document.querySelectorAll('.CodeMirror-scroll');
    for (i = 0; i < cms.length; i++) {
      cms[i].style.height = '100%';
    }*/

}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.getScript('/myscript.js')` worked.